# ConTeXt manual ToC style

Tags: table-of-contents, context

How can i replicate the table of contents style from the [ConTeXt manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-enp.pdf) with ConTeXt?

In particular, I like that page numbers are not aligned right und sections have no line breaks between them. Looking at the [sources](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/manuals/context/), i cannot figure out how to reproduce that.

Comment: Just have a look in this file: http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/contextman/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Fcontext-reference%2Fen%2Fst-contents.tex&view=markup

Comment: @Patrick: that should be an answer

Answer (score 3):

The [source code of this manual is available online](http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/contextman) (and you can help enhancing the document by reporting any errors or telling the people on the [context mailing list](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) how you liked it), so just look at the file that generates the toc ([st-contents.tex](http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/contextman/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/context-reference/en/st-contents.tex&view=markup)).

Comment: Ok, essentially: \setuplist[chapter][alternative=a,pagecommand=\hskip10pt,interaction=all]
\setuplist[section,subsection][alternative=d,margin=2em] However, interaction=all for section,subsections makes the page numbers disappear. Also, alternative=d is undefined?